# All VS projects now throwing Error CS8630 Invalid 'nullable' value: 'Enable' for C# 7.1. Please use language version '8.0' or greater

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, no idea what's happened here. Am on 17.8.5, multiple windows forms projects in C# (targeting 4.8.1) are throwing this error:

Error CS8630 Invalid 'nullable' value: 'Enable' for C# 7.1. Please use language version '8.0' or greater.

No clue why, but I did find this as a solution - but I have to add it to every broken project:
https://devblog.dinobansigan.com/invalid-nullable-value-enable-for-c-7-3

What's happened here, any suggestions? I opened VS last night to find that none of my projects were showing "peek definition", "go to base" etc in the right-click menu, they were all grayed out. That problem seems to have gone away now (but remains in visual micro/Arduino stuff) and has been replaced by the above. Can't think of anything I've added, no new features or apps, no major upgrades to anything bar Jan24 Windows updates the other night. Except... I installed Avalonia (see below).

Am at a loss to explain what's going on - anyone?

Thanks

edit: and ofc, having posted this, I just found this link, and the keyword Avalonia was mentioned: [How do I make newer Visual Studio versions use proper nullable behavior for older projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586954/how-do-i-make-newer-visual-studio-versions-use-proper-nullable-behavior-for-olde)

Although none of my projects use Avalonia (bar the one I stood up to investigate), is it possible it's leaking settings at the VS installation level and upsetting my other stuff?

Comment: Fixed the grayed out menu section, I'd moved the intellisense database to a location outwith the project. Issue with the nullable error remains.

Comment: Do you have any Directory.Build.props file in your folder hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, I just found this today - please see below

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

right below the

```
<TargetFramework>
```

tag from your csproj file and then restart project.

I also suggest you to delete bin and obj folders before opening it

Comment: No "nullable" in the csproj. Cleared the bin/obj completely, still the same issue.

Adding
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
Fixes it - but why?

Comment: Same in CLI, cleaned/rebuilt, restarting, rebooting, you name it. Again, all code that worked fine recently. Project also builds fine in github actions.

Just opened a solution, untouched since 2022. Same error for all 3 projects.

My tablet doesn't have Avalonia on it, so I tried compiling the exact same project on it. Same error !

So, not an Avalonia issue, and not an issue particular to one machine (tablet is on 17.8.4, so pre-VSupdate). Both machines have had the Jan24 updates tho...

Comment: Changing this also brings it back to life:
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>

But the main version in repo says 7.1.. and that compiles OK too! No changes of note between that and the copy on disk, so very strange

Comment: @lansalot Do you have any Directory.Build.props file in your folder hierarchy?

Comment: YES!! In the root of my folder where all the github repos are, and look at this!

    <Project>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <AvaloniaVersion>11.0.2</AvaloniaVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>

It was Avalonia then! Renamed the file and everything works once again. Thanks @WenbinGeng, I really appreciate it